# error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/socket.h'

Tags: python-2.7, network-programming, installation, package

I was installing package pynids(https://jon.oberheide.org/pynids/). I was unale to find sys.h. I am using window7 and python 2.7 and pynids-0.6.1

```
C:\Users\himanshu.dua\Downloads\pynids-0.6.1\pynids-0.6.1>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'nidsmodule' extension
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ilibnids-1.24\src -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -IC
:\python27\include -IC:\python27\PC /Tcnidsmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Rele
ase\nidsmodule.obj
nidsmodule.c
nidsmodule.c(24) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/socket.h':
No such file or directory
error: command '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' fa
iled with exit status 2
```

Comment: same problem here, I'm coming to the conclusion that this isn't setup to work on windows...

Comment: As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638604/where-does-one-get-the-sys-socket-h-header-source-file, the header `<sys/socket.h>` is not defined in windows.