# How to run a client server program on dev c++?

Tags: c++, c, client-server

I have the client and server program separately. All I need is a step by step guidance on how to run them on dev c++. There are no issues with the code. When I compile the codes, the compilers says: sys/socket.h: no such file or directory. How do I correct that? The code is in c++. And if it can not be run in Dev, kindly tell me in which environment can it be run. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [Where does one get the “sys/socket.h” header/source file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4638604/583833)

Answer (score 1):

sys/socket.h, along with many other headers you'll find, is not available on Windows.

Have a look at winsock2.h