# Cocos2d-x missing sys/socket.h

Tags: c++, windows, windows-phone, cocos2d-x

I built my game on iOS and Android platform successfully, but when I run Cocos2d-x with proj.win8.1-universal, many issues appear:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'sys/socket.h': No such file or
>   directory
>   (D:\iLucky3.9\iLucky\proj.win8.1-universal\App.Shared....\Classes\AppDelegate.cpp)  iLucky.WindowsPhone d:\mygame\cocos2d\external\curl\include\ios\curl\curlbuild-32.h 152

Help me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things I'm thinking of here. The foremost being that windows doesn't ship with a socket.h. See [this question about windows socket.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638604/where-does-one-get-the-sys-socket-h-header-source-file) tldr; use winsock.h

I also notice there's a "ios" in your path for curlbuild. I have absolutely no idea if that matters since I don't know how your project is set up.

Comment: I don't know why the file ios\curl\curlbuild-32.h be included on my project when I start proj.win8.1-universal project, I can't remove it.

Comment: It is likely included by something else you included. The issue could be related, since curl is the name of a well-known networking library that almost certainly uses sockets. It could be a build configuration/includes issue. Or it could be nothing, it's just a directory path.