# How to include sys/socket.h file in clion?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, operating-system

I searched and did not found a clear answer. I am using Clion 2020.2 on Windows 10. I do not know how to include <sys/socket.h> file among others like <sys/un.h> so I can use its functions. I am a beginner learning about OS and using Clion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does one get the "sys/socket.h" header/source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638604/where-does-one-get-the-sys-socket-h-header-source-file)