# Good lightweight C or C++ master-slave networking library

Tags: c, network-programming

I have a C/C++ server process that needs to broadcast data to some number of client programs on other computers. Client programs are also C/C++. I need a reliable and lightweight communication library that will allow my server to communicate with any number of clients. Clients must be able to detect when a socket connection is no longer open, hopefully without having to constantly poll the server. I do not want to use something huge like Boost. I want something lightweight and simple. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214965/cross-platform-networking-api). It looks like Qt may include what you need, and it's known as relatively simple to use. SDL.net is another alternative that might meet those requirements.